# Querysets between differnt app models with combined filters

Tags: python, django

I am trying to combine Django-hitcount order_by('-hits') filter with my own custom model. I need to get first 5 items with max number of hits. But couldn't make it work for homepage view.

Here is the code:

products/models.py:

```
class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset().active()

    def get_related(self, instance):
        products_one = self.get_queryset().filter(categories__in=instance.categories.all())
        products_two = self.get_queryset().filter(default=instance.default)
        qs = (products_one | products_two).exclude(id=instance.id).distinct()
        return qs


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)
    hits = models.ForeignKey(HitCount)

    objects = ProductManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]
```

Django-hitcount/models.py:

```
class HitCount(models.Model):

    hits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField('object ID')
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')

    objects = HitCountManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-hits',)
```

home/views.py:

```
from products.models import Product
from hitcount.models import Hitcount

trending = Product.objects.all().order_by('-hits')[:5]
```

I created a foreignkey to integrate hitcount with my product model. Please assist how could I get first 5 products with max hits. I've used MAX aggregate option but it doesn't work. I am new to djagno so looking for a solution.

Comment: It's not very clear how your models are structured (what is the generic foreign key in the `HitCount` model supposed to point to?). However if `Product` has a foreign key to `HitCount` then to order by the number of hits you would do `Product.objects.all().order_by('-hits__hits')`, where the second `hits` is the `hits` field on the `HitCount` model.

Comment: You were right and this is the mistake I was making not to refer hits properly but still I can't get it working in order_by maximum hits. Also please take a look at Django-hitcount for details. Its a reusable package.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.annotate()` function with `Max` to calc that and after that just sorting it and limit the first five results:

```
>>> products = Product.objects.all()
>>> products = products.annotate(hits=Max('hits__hits'))
>>> products = products.order_by('-hits')[:5]
>>> # Displaying the results
>>> products.values('hits')
<ProductQuerySet [{'hits': 30}, {'hits': 8}, {'hits': 7}, {'hits': 6}, {'hits': 4}]>
```

If you have more questions about how this work, look at the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet